# How to add jwt token integration with fastapi authlib oauth?

Tags: python-3.x, oauth, jwt, fastapi

I have this main.py file. I am creating a jwt token here at /auth endpoint. After the token is generated, now I am unable to redirect it to base path("/"). How can I achieve that. If I try to access the / path, i get redirected to auth endpoint with the bearer token displayed. Any help or pointers on how this can be done.

main.py

```
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
oauth = OAuth()

CONF_URL = "https://localhost:8080/.well-known/openid-configuration"
oauth.register(
    name="cad",
    server_metadata_url=CONF_URL,
    client_id=settings.CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=settings.CLIENT_SECRET,
    client_kwargs={"scope": "openid email profile authorization_group"},
)
oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl='/auth')

def create_access_token(*, data: dict, expires_delta: datetime.timedelta = None):
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({'exp': expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, "abcd", algorithm="HS256")
    return encoded_jwt


def create_token(id):
    access_token_expires = datetime.timedelta(minutes=120)
    access_token = create_access_token(data={'sub': id}, expires_delta=access_token_expires)
    return access_token


@app.middleware("http")
async def authorize(request: Request, call_next):
    if not (request.scope["path"].startswith("/login") or request.scope["path"].startswith("/auth")):
        if not is_session_okay(request.session):
            return RedirectResponse(url="/login")
    return await call_next(request)


@app.get("/login")
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for("auth")
    return await oauth.cad.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)


@app.get("/auth")
async def auth(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.cad.authorize_access_token(request)
    except OAuthError as error:
        return HTMLResponse(f"<h1>{error.error}</h1>")
    user = await oauth.cad.parse_id_token(request, token)
    access_token = create_token(user['sub'])
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}


@app.get("/", tags=["Web-UI"])
def index():
    frontend_root = "./ui"
    return FileResponse(str(frontend_root) + "/index.html", media_type="text/html")
```

Comment: Did you try to follow the official auth jwt implementation ?
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/
You have a very good example

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using fastapi you should use it's jwt implementation.

The framework provide classes especialy for that => `OAuth2PasswordBearer` and `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm`

the doc on this is available in [the advanced documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/#hash-and-verify-the-passwords):

(from the doc)

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm


class Token(BaseModel):
    access_token: str
    token_type: str


oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")
app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/token", response_model=Token)
async def login_for_access_token(form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()):
    user = authenticate_user(fake_users_db, form_data.username, form_data.password)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": user.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}
```

Comment: I can't use OAuth2PasswordRequestForm , my fastapi app connects to an external SSO link for authentication.